# Obstacle Avoidance in Unity, using raycasts. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am using some rudimentary obstacle avoidance algorithm to avoid obstacles, however i am having issues with the right and left sensors. When both are active. they will cancel their rotations and not rotate at all. Also having a bit of trouble figuring out hit.normals via the front sensor.

```
    ray = new Ray(transform.position + Vector3.up, transform.forward);
    Vector3 posInicial = transform.position;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 55f)) // Front sensor
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == ("Pick Up")) // If robot detects pick up, it goes towards it
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point, Color.red);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hit.point, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, -80 * Time.deltaTime, 0); // Rotate if front sensor doesn't detect pick up
            Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point, Color.blue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime; // Go forward
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point, Color.white);
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast(posInicial, Quaternion.AngleAxis(45f, transform.up) * transform.forward, out hit2, 20f))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, -80 * Time.deltaTime, 0); // Rotate left if right detected
        Debug.DrawLine(posInicial, hit2.point, Color.yellow);
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast(posInicial, Quaternion.AngleAxis(-45f, transform.up) * transform.forward, out hit3, 20f))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 80 * Time.deltaTime, 0); // rotate right if detected left
        Debug.DrawLine(posInicial, hit3.point, Color.cyan);
    }
}
```

Comment: So... what's your problem? Are you looking for a better algorithm to avoid obstacles?

Comment: Kind of, at the moment if both left and right sensors detect, they will cancel rotations and get stuck between a corner of a wall

Comment: what would you like to happen when both sensors detect?

Comment: For it to reverse, but it would to overlap my go forward else statement.

Comment: Maybe instead of doing two if-statements for left/right, do it as an if/else. That way, it'll only try and turn one way in a frame.

Comment: I think i need to find another way to look at this problem. I replaced the left right if statements by the if/else, but the rotation gets stuck on a loop.

Comment: Any algorithms you would suggest looking into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to implement this on your own. If it is because you are interested in the algorithm and you are trying to extrapolate it in the future to the real world, it's fine.

But just in case, there is already something called NavMesh in Unity, which basically provide a AI to gameobejcts, for example enemies, which make them identify obstacles so to avoid them when moving from one point to another in the scene.

- Select scene geometry that should affect the navigation – walkable
  surfaces and obstacles.
- Check Navigation Static on to include    selected objects in the
  NavMesh baking process.
- Adjust the bake    settings to match your agent size.
- Click bake to build    the NavMesh

Once you have the scene baked, you can add the navmesh to a gameobject:

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent nav; 

    function Awake ()
    {
        nav = GetComponent(NavMeshAgent);
    }

    //So here it will be chasing the player
    function Update ()
    {
        nav.SetDestination (player.position);
    }
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html) and follow this [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/enemy-one?playlist=17144)

Comment: Trying to avoid Navmesh atm since i want the AI to scan the area. My previous build of the game was using Navmesh however, thanks anyway.